# Caching Strategy for a Deep, Traversable Egocentric Graph

Tags: database, performance, caching, d3.js, force-layout

**Firstly, let me explain what I'm building:**

- I have a D3.js Force Layout graph which is rooted at the center, and has a bunch of nodes spread around it. The center node is an Entity of some sort, the nodes around it are other Entities which are somehow related to the root. The edges are the actual relations (i.e. how the two are related).
- The outer nodes can be clicked to center the target Entity and load its relations
- This graph is "Egocentric" in the sense that every time a node is clicked, it becomes the center, and only relations *directly* involved with itself are displayed.

**My Setup, in case any of it matters:**

- I'm serving an API through Node.js, which translates requests into queries to a CouchDB server with huge data sets.
- D3.js is used for layout, and aside from jQuery and Bootstrap, I'm not using any other client-side libraries. If any would help with this caching task, I'm open to suggestions :)

**My Ideas:**

- I could easily grab a few levels of the graph each time (recurse through the process of listing and expanding children a few times) but since clicking on any given node loads completely unrelated data, it is not guaranteed to yield a high percentage of the similar data as was loaded for the root. This seems like a complete waste, and actually a step in the *opposite* direction -- I'd end up doing *more* processing this way!
- I can easily maintain a hash table of Entities that have already been retrieved, and check the list before requesting data for that entity from the server. I'll probably end up doing this regardless of the cache strategy I implement, since it's a really simple way of reducing queries.

**Now, how do you suggest I cache this data?**

Is there any super-effective strategy you can think of for doing this kind of caching? Both server-and-client-side options are greatly welcomed. A *ton* of data is involved in this process, and any reduction of querying/processing puts me miles ahead of the game.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side I would have nodes, and have their children either be an array of children, or else a function that serves as a promise of those children.  When you click on a given node, if you have data, display it immediately.  Else send off an AJAX request that will fill it.

Whenever you display a node (not centered), create an asynchronous list of AJAX requests for the children of the displayed nodes and start requesting them.  That way when the user clicks, there is a chance that you already have it cached.  And if not, well, you tried and cost them nothing.

Once you have it working, decide how many levels deep it makes sense to go.  My guess is that the magic number is likely to be 1.  Beyond that the return in responsiveness falls off rapidly, while the server load rises rapidly.  But having clicks come back ASAP is a pretty big UI win.

Comment: This is a good strategy in terms of responsiveness, but overall, the main intent is to decrease server load. I think having all of those wasted requests using up server resources would impact performance more than the individual increase in performance that could be seen from pre-loading all of the nodes. What do you think?

Comment: @BraedenP It depends on your server architecture.  If you do things right, it is all distributed anyways, so you can easily scale the server up to any usage level.  And besides, you can serve ridiculous amounts of stuff on commodity hardware - wait until you can prove that a problem actually exists before worrying about it.

Comment: True. I'd like to make this very scalable, but I'll definitely give it a shot and see how it fairs on some performance metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do two things:

1. Reduce the number of requests you make
2. Reduce the cost of requests

As btilly points out, you're probably best requesting the related nodes for each visible node, so that if they are clicked the visualisation is immediately responsive -- you don't want the query plus transit time as a response lag.

However, if you have this great need to reduce the number of requests, it suggests your requests themselves are too costly, since the total load is `requestCost * numRequests`. Consider finding ways to pre-calculate the set of nodes related to each node, so that the request is a read request rather than a full DB query. If you're thinking that sounds hard, it's just what Google do every time you search for a new thing; they can't search the internet every time you start typing, so they do that ahead of time, and cache.

This may mean some amount of denormalisation; if you have a cache *and* a query, there is no guarantee they are in sync, but the question there is whether your dataset changes; is it write once, read many?

To minimise the space needed by all these nodes and their relations, see it more as a particle interaction problem; by partitioning the space you may be able to group nodes so that you only need query a group of nodes for its aggregate neighbours, and store that. That way you can do a much smaller filtration on each request rather than a full DB query. If it's O(n log n) and you make n a hundred times smaller, it's more than 100x faster.